# poisson distribution (dpois) integration R

Tags: r

I'm trying to integrate the poisson distribution (dpois) in R but I get an incorrect answer (0 with absolute error 0) and 21 warnings. I don't understand how R is digesting my simple meal and why it pukes out 21 warnings.

```
    dpoisd1 <- function(x) {dpois(x, 0.0001)}
    dpoisd1(1:20)
    integrate(dpoisd1, lower = 1, upper = 20)
```

it yields 0 with absolute error < 0 and some 21 warnings. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me my mistake(s).

Answer (score 5):

Use `warnings` to have a look at the warnings:

```
warnings()
#Warning messages:
#1: In dpois(x, 1e-04) : non-integer x = 10.500000
#<snip>
```

The first parameter of `dpois` must be a non-negative integer (see `help("dpois")`). `integrate` passes non-integer values to it. In fact, it is not clear, what you want to calculate. You are trying to integrate a discrete density function. Possibly you want `ppois`, the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Just to amplify, with discrete probability distributions like the Poisson, you can sum probabilities by simply adding them up. Integration's only needed for continuous distributions. So here, use `sum(dpoisd1(1:20))` or (as Roland hints) `ppois(20, .0001) - ppois(0, .0001)`